# Upload data and image base 64 to rest server as truncated

Tags: image, upload, server, base64, truncated

I'm using advanced rest console of chrome and i'm sending a rest request to a server that saves an image to database.

below the header data and the body of the request:

*Header:*

> Content-Type: image/jpg; charset=UTF-8

*Body:*

> device_id=1442045686166&id_utente=1&id_attivita=-1&id_prodotto=115&file=/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/...

the server, not mine, it all comes back ok but here is the result
[image returned](http://oi61.tinypic.com/152n6sm.jpg)

The other images were uploaded from Android application that sends requests to the same server!

The server is a java web application deployed on jboss application server.

This is the html part of retrive image:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Immagine</label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <i ng-hide="imageSrc">Nessuna immagine selezionata</i>
                                    <img ng-hide="!imageSrc" ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" on-error-src="images/noimg.png" spinner-on-load/>
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="file" id="imageInputFile" name="imageInputFile" ng-model="imageInputFile" ng-change="uploadFile(this)" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" base-sixty-four-input maxsize="500" accept="image/*">
                                            <p class="help-block">Scegli un'immagine in locale.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And this is the angularjs code:

```
$scope.uploadImage = function (id_prodotto) {
        trace("uploadImage, inizio");

        var img64 = $scope.imageSrc.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");

        $scope.bodyRawImg =
            'device_id=' + $scope.key +
            '&id_utente=' + $scope.BeanUtente[0].id_utente +
            '&id_attivita=' + $scope.BeanUtente[0].id_attivita +
            '&id_prodotto=' + id_prodotto +
            '&file=' + img64;

        trace("uploadImage, $scope.bodyRawImg " + $scope.bodyRawImg);

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: ($location.absUrl().split("/easyMenu/"))[0] + '/app/file/uploadFoto',
            async: false,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'
            },
            data: $scope.bodyRawImg,
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { // success
            trace("uploadImage, success");
            $scope.result = (data || []);
            trace("uploadImage response: " + JSON.stringify($scope.result));
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { // error
            trace("uploadImage, error");
        });

        $scope.cambioImmagine = false;
```

Comment: What sort of server is this? Why does your base64 encoded data start with `/9j/`? Post an actual, *complete* request and tell us how you generate that

Comment: hi, i added the info on main post, my base64 encoded data start with /9j/ because in my code i replace the first data var img64 = $scope.imageSrc.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");